# Correcting characters in a string?

Tags: c#, char

I need to correct unwanted chars in a string.
unwanted characters:

"c" instead of "ç"
"i" instead of "ı"
"u" instead of "ü"
"g" instead of "ğ"
"o" instead of "ö"
"s" instead of "ş"

I have written this method. But it doesnt work.

```
public string UrlCorrection(string text)
    {
        text = (text.ToLower()).Trim();
        var length = text.Length;
        char chr;
        string newtext="";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            chr = text[i];
            switch (chr)
            {
                case 'ç':
                    newtext = text.Replace("ç", "c");
                    break;
                case 'ı':
                    newtext = text.Replace("ı", "i");
                    break;
                case 'ü':
                    newtext = text.Replace("ü", "u");
                    break;
                case 'ğ':
                    newtext = text.Replace("ğ", "g");
                    break;
                case 'ö':
                    newtext = text.Replace("ö", "o");
                    break;
                case 'ş':
                    newtext = text.Replace("ş", "s");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        newtext = text;
        return text;
    }
```

How do i implenet this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
public string UrlCorrection (string text)
{
    StringBuilder correctedText = new StringBuilder (text);

    return correctedText.Replace("ç", "c")
                        .Replace("ı", "i")
                        .Replace("ü", "u")
                        .Replace("ğ", "g")
                        .Replace("ö", "o")
                        .Replace("ş", "s")
                        .ToString ();
}
```

Comment: It will not work, because he calls text.Replace every time. Only the last matched character will be replaced.

Comment: not. this not solved my problem. I dont know where is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you can just do this:

```
newtext = text.Replace("ç", "c"); 
newtext = newtext.Replace("ı", "i"); 
newtext = newtext.Replace("ü", "u"); 
newtext = newtext.Replace("ğ", "g"); 
newtext = newtext.Replace("ö", "o"); 
newtext = newtext.Replace("ş", "s");
```

No need for the switch/case/indexing craziness.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not working because you're trying to match the char's directly. My method works and I used unicode codes to match the special chars, using this [unicode chart](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html). You don't have to loop through each char because `Replace()` replaces *all* instances of that char.

```
public string UrlCorrection(string text)
{
    text = text.ToLower().Trim();
    text = text
        .Replace('\u00E7','c')
        .Replace('\u0131','i')
        .Replace('\u00FC','u')
        .Replace('\u011F','g')
        .Replace('\u00F6','o')
        .Replace('\u015F','s');

    return text;
}
```

I've tested this with your special chars and it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you come from a C background and fail to consider that strings are immutable in .net (as well as in Java).

Your function can return a new string, with all characters replaced by their substitutes, but the original string will be unchanged.

basically, you can take klausbyskov's version, but instead of calling it like this:

```
UrlCorrection(url);
```

you have to call e.g.

```
url=UrlCorrection(url);
```